# Double enter press for reading data socket

Tags: c#, sockets

i'm using this code (from minimalistic telnet) to do a telnet session with a sample server, i have the problem that i have to press two times enter to read/send the output from server, how this is possible? i have to use some async reading system?

```
    //create a new telnet connection to hostname "gobelijn" on port "23"
    TelnetConnection tc = new TelnetConnection("gobelijn", 23);

    //login with user "root",password "rootpassword", using a timeout of 100ms, 
    //and show server output
    string s = tc.Login("root", "rootpassword",100);
    Console.Write(s);

    // server output should end with "$" or ">", otherwise the connection failed
    string prompt = s.TrimEnd();
    prompt = s.Substring(prompt.Length -1,1);
    if (prompt != "$" && prompt != ">" )
        throw new Exception("Connection failed");

    prompt = "";

    // while connected
    while (tc.IsConnected && prompt.Trim() != "exit" )
    {
        // display server output
        Console.Write(tc.Read());

        // send client input to server
        prompt = Console.ReadLine();
        tc.WriteLine(prompt);

        // display server output
        Console.Write(tc.Read());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("***DISCONNECTED");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is there a `tc.Flush()` method you need to call to send the data after `.WriteLine`? It could delay it otherwise.

Comment: I imagine the issue is that `tc.Read()` is not a blocking operation, i.e. it won't wait until there is data available. Your code does the write so quickly that it doesn't have chance for the server to send anything back before you call `Read()` so you don't get anything back. Then your code gets around to the `Console.ReadLine()` which makes your application pause, and while you're typing something the server has had chance to send some data, so it's picked up the second time.